# How to use Scikit for mapping words to indexes starting from index=1

Tags: python, mapping, nlp, scikit-learn, vocabulary

Is there a way to use Scikit-learn to map words to indexes where it starts from 1 and not from 0?

**Example - Pseudo code**:

```
sequence = ['welcome', 'home', 'shimon']
dict = mapping_func(sequence)

print(dict['welcome'])
print(dict['home'])
print(dict['shimon'])
```

**While the output of this code is:**

1

2

3

I need this option in order to zero padding sequences and if the value 0 belongs to a key it might (and probably will) lead to faulty results.

Comment: I don't see why it will lead to faulty results? Python arrays, lists, etc. are 0 index. If you explain more, we can show you such that the 0 index will not be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of words such as `sequence = ['welcome', 'home', 'shimon']` and you pad it with 0s you will have `sequence= ['welcome', 'home', 'shimon', 0, 0]`. Then you can always do l.index(`welcome`) to retrieve the index. If you are interested in cases where a word will have more than one index, you can use list comprehension.

```
>>>sequence= ['welcome', 'home', 'shimon', 0, 0]
>>>indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(sequence) if x == 0]
>>>indices
[3,4]
>>>indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(sequence) if x == 'welcome']
>>>indices
[0]
```

Comment: I know how to do it in general. I was asking about doing it with Scikit, especially with CountVectorizer